# Function not executing on background thread

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I'm trying to apply RX to Android. I want when a button is clicked, to download something from web and display it.

My problem is that **HttpClient.connect() executes on the mainThread** instead of a background one.
The call to HttpClient.connect() executes as a function passed to Observable.map()

```
Observable<Integer> dayDeltas =  Obs.obsToSequence(Obs.Observable(textView)); //transforms click events to observable
Observable<String> dates = dayDeltas.map(...).map(...)
dates.map(Obs.dateToWebPage()) // calls http.connect()
     .map(Obs.parseEvents())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
     .subscribe(updateTextView(textView));

public static Observable<Object> Observable(final TextView text) {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
                final Object event = new Object();
                text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.e("click", "click");
                        subscriber.onNext(event);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Now my naive interpretation is that since i have **.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())** every function/operator on the observable should execute in a new thread, including .map(f). Clearly this is not what is happening, so what part of this chain does execute on new threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`subscribeOn` is there to trigger subscription side-effects. In your setup, it will register the callback to capture the button press on the new thread but when the press happens, the onNext emission is triggered by the main thread. The chain, including the network connect then executes on the main thread.

You have to put a new `observeOn(Schedulers.io())` before the connecting method to make sure the reception of the button press event happens off the main thread.

**Edit:**

```
//transforms click events to observable
Observable<Integer> dayDeltas =  Obs.obsToSequence(Obs.Observable(textView));

Observable<String> dates = dayDeltas.map(...).map(...)
dates
 .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) // <------------------------------------------ add
 .map(Obs.dateToWebPage()) // calls http.connect()
 .map(Obs.parseEvents())
 .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
 //.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // <------------------------------- remove
 .subscribe(updateTextView(textView));
```

Comment: I tried putting obserOn(newThread) above the .connect() function
dates.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map(Obs.dateToWebPage())
but i get the same errror: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 2):

After carefully reading the [Scheduling and Threading RX doc](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/15_SchedulingAndThreading.html), i have the solution:

```
 dates
       .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .map(Obs.dateToWebPage())
```

In my original code, the schedulers passed to observeOn/subscribeOn were reversed and in the wrong place.